# control buffer for display large xml file vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

Problem : I have dozen of xml files in amount between 1 to 5 MP.  using vb.net with ASP.NET
How can I display xml files by controlling amount of display by byte 
the case display which i have to implement once the page is loaded i need to display 200kb ,once users scroll down i need to load more till the whole xml

or other case  once the page is loaded ,display 200kb of the xml file ,show it to the user and continue loading

is it possible to implement this idea.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you if the characters are ASCII characters, you can assume that each character is 1 byte. So, just take a substring of length n. If they are encoded in another fashion, you'll have to find out what encoding is used and how many bytes a character holds.

Comment: well, are you suggested to use substring function , it is good idea , thanks for help ,,, i may use your idea